How do i parse this value reassignment properly?
I am building a python compiler using llvmlite and python.
I am working on variable reassignment at the moment and keep getting this error;
Parsing expression, current token: Token[TokenType.INT : 4 : Line 2 : Position 33]
Left expression: <AST.IntegerLiteral object at 0x100fc8ef0>
Parsing expression, current token: Token[TokenType.EQ : = : Line 4 : Position 42]
Parsing expression, current token: Token[TokenType.ASTERISK : * : Line 4 : Position 46]
Parsing expression, current token: Token[TokenType.INT : 2 : Line 4 : Position 49]
Left expression: <AST.IntegerLiteral object at 0x101044920>
Parsing expression, current token: Token[TokenType.IDENT : a : Line 6 : Position 64]
Left expression: <AST.IdentifierLiteral object at 0x100fc9b50>
No prefix parse function found for token 'TokenType.EQ'
No prefix parse function found for token 'TokenType.ASTERISK'

Here are the required files to help debug:
AST.py:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from enum import Enum

class NodeType(Enum):
    Program = "Program"

    #Statements
    ExpressionStatement = "ExpressionStatement"
    VariableStatement = "VariableStatement"
    FunctionStatement = "FunctionStatement"
    BlockStatement = "BlockStatement"
    ReturnStatement = "ReturnStatement"
    AssignStatement = "AssignStatement"

    #Expression
    InfixExpression = "InfixExpression"

    #Literals
    IntegerLiteral = "IntegerLiteral"
    FloatLiteral = "FloatLiteral"
    IdentifierLiteral = "IdentifierLiteral"

class Node(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def json(self) -> dict:
        pass


class Statement(Node):
    pass

class Expression(Node):
    pass

class Program(Node):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.statements: list[Statement] = []

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.Program

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "statements": [{stmt.type().value: stmt.json()} for stmt in self.statements]
        }


#Region statements
class ExpressionStatement(Statement):
    def __init__(self, expr: Expression = None) -> None:
        self.expr: Expression = expr

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.ExpressionStatement

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "expr": self.expr.json() if self.expr is not None else None
        }

class VariableStatement(Statement):
    def __init__(self, name: Expression = None, value: Expression = None, value_type: str = None) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.value_type = value_type

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.VariableStatement

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "name": self.name.json() if self.name is not None else None,
            "value": self.value.json() if self.value is not None else None,
            "value_type": self.value_type
        }

class BlockStatement(Statement):
    def __init__(self, statements: list[Statement] = None) -> None:
        self.statements = statements if statements is not None else []

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.BlockStatement

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "statements": [stmt.json() for stmt in self.statements]
        }

class ReturnStatement(Statement):
    def __init__(self, return_value: Expression = None) -> None:
        self.return_value = return_value

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.ReturnStatement

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "return_value": self.return_value.json()
        }

class FunctionStatement(Statement):
    def __init__(self, parameters: list = [], body: BlockStatement = None, name = None, return_type: str = None) -> None:
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.body = body
        self.name = name
        self.return_type = return_type

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.FunctionStatement

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "name": self.name.json() if self.name is not None else None,
            "return_type": self.return_type,
            "parameters": [p.json() for p in self.parameters],
            "body": self.body.json() if self.body is not None else None
        }

class AssignStatement(Statement):
    def __init__(self, ident: Expression = None, right_value: Expression = None) -> None:
        self.ident = ident
        self.right_value = right_value

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.AssignStatement

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "ident": self.ident.json(),
            "right_value": self.right_value.json()
        }

class InfixExpression(Expression):
    def __init__(self, left_node: Expression, operator: str, right_node: Expression = None) -> None:
        self.left_node: Expression = left_node
        self.operator: str = operator
        self.right_node: Expression = right_node

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.InfixExpression

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "left_node": self.left_node.json(),
            "operator": self.operator,
            "right_node": self.right_node.json()
        }

#Region Literals
class IntegerLiteral(Expression):
    def __init__(self, value: int = None) -> None:
        self.value: int = value

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.IntegerLiteral

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "value": self.value
        }

class FloatLiteral(Expression):
    def __init__(self, value: float = None) -> None:
        self.value: float = value

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.FloatLiteral

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "value": self.value
        }

class IdentifierLiteral(Expression):
    def __init__(self, value: str = None) -> None:
        self.value: str = value

    def type(self) -> NodeType:
        return NodeType.IdentifierLiteral

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "type": self.type().value,
            "value": self.value,
        }

Parser.py:
from Lexer import Lexer
from Token import Token, TokenType
from typing import Callable
from enum import Enum, auto

from AST import Statement, Expression, Program
from AST import ExpressionStatement, VariableStatement, FunctionStatement, ReturnStatement, BlockStatement, AssignStatement
from AST import  InfixExpression
from AST import IntegerLiteral, FloatLiteral, IdentifierLiteral

#Precedence Types
class PrecedenceType(Enum):
    P_LOWEST  = 0
    P_EQUALS = auto()
    P_LESSGREATER = auto()
    P_SUM = auto()
    P_PRODUCT = auto()
    P_EXPONENT = auto()
    P_PREFIX = auto()
    P_CALL = auto()
    P_INDEX = auto()

#Precedence Mapping
PRECEDENCES: dict[TokenType, PrecedenceType] = {
    TokenType.PLUS: PrecedenceType.P_SUM,
    TokenType.MINUS: PrecedenceType.P_SUM,
    TokenType.SLASH: PrecedenceType.P_PRODUCT,
    TokenType.ASTERISK: PrecedenceType.P_PRODUCT,
    TokenType.MODULUS: PrecedenceType.P_PRODUCT,
    TokenType.POW: PrecedenceType.P_EXPONENT,
}

class Parser:
    def __init__(self, lexer: Lexer) -> None:
        self.lexer = lexer

        self.errors: list[str] = []

        self.current_token: Token = None
        self.peek_token: Token = None

        self.prefix_parse_fns: dict[TokenType, Callable] = {
            TokenType.IDENT: self.__parse_identifier,
            TokenType.INT: self.__parse_int_literal,
            TokenType.FLOAT: self.__parse_float_literal,
            TokenType.LPAREN: self.__parse_grouped_expression,
        }
        self.infix_parse_fns: dict[TokenType, Callable] = {
            TokenType.PLUS: self.__parse_infix_expression,
            TokenType.MINUS: self.__parse_infix_expression,
            TokenType.SLASH: self.__parse_infix_expression,
            TokenType.ASTERISK: self.__parse_infix_expression,
            TokenType.POW: self.__parse_infix_expression,
            TokenType.MODULUS: self.__parse_infix_expression,
        }

        self.__next_token()
        self.__next_token()

    #Region parser helpers
    def __next_token(self) -> None:
        self.current_token = self.peek_token
        self.peek_token = self.lexer.next_token()

    def __current_token_is(self, tt: TokenType) -> bool:
        return self.current_token.type == tt

    def __peek_token_is(self, tt: TokenType) -> bool:
        return self.peek_token == tt

    def __peek_token(self, tt: TokenType) -> bool:
        return self.peek_token.type == tt

    def __expect_peek(self, tt: TokenType) -> bool:
        if self.__peek_token(tt):
            self.__next_token()
            return True
        else:
            self.__peek_token(tt)
            return False

    def __current_precedence(self) -> PrecedenceType:
        prec: int | None = PRECEDENCES.get(self.current_token.type)
        if prec is None:
            return PrecedenceType.P_LOWEST
        return prec

    def __peek_precedence(self) -> PrecedenceType:
        prec: int | None = PRECEDENCES.get(self.peek_token.type)
        if prec is None:
            return PrecedenceType.P_LOWEST
        return prec

    def __peek_error(self, tt: TokenType) -> None:
        self.errors.append(f"Unexpected token '{tt}', got {self.peek_token} instead.")

    def __no_prefix_parse_fn_error(self, tt: TokenType):
        self.errors.append(f"No prefix parse function found for token '{tt}'")

    def parse_program(self) -> Program:
        program = Program()
        while self.current_token.type != TokenType.EOF:
            stmt = self.__parse_statement()
            if stmt is not None:
                program.statements.append(stmt)
            self.__next_token()
            if self.current_token.type == TokenType.SEMICOLON:
                self.__next_token()
        return program

    def __parse_statement(self) -> Statement:
        if self.current_token.type == TokenType.IDENT and self.__peek_token_is(TokenType.EQ):
            return self.__parse_assign_statement()

        match self.current_token.type:
            case TokenType.IDENT:
                return self.__parse_variable_statement()
            case TokenType.DEF:
                return self.__parse_function_statement()
            case TokenType.RETURN:
                return self.__parse_return_statement()
            case _:
                return self.__parse_expression_statement()


    def __parse_expression_statement(self) -> ExpressionStatement:
        expr = self.__parse_expression(PrecedenceType.P_LOWEST)

        if self.__peek_token_is(TokenType.SEMICOLON):
            self.__next_token()

        stmt: ExpressionStatement = ExpressionStatement(expr=expr)

        return stmt

    def __parse_variable_statement(self) -> VariableStatement:
        # a: int = 10;
        stmt: VariableStatement = VariableStatement()

        if not self.__current_token_is(TokenType.IDENT):
            return None

        stmt.name = IdentifierLiteral(value=self.current_token.literal)

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.COLON):
            return None

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.TYPE):
            return None

        stmt.value_type = self.current_token.literal

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.EQ):
            return None

        self.__next_token()

        stmt.value = self.__parse_expression(PrecedenceType.P_LOWEST)

        while not self.__current_token_is(TokenType.SEMICOLON) and self.__current_token_is(TokenType.EOF):
            self.__next_token()

        return stmt

    def __parse_function_statement(self) -> FunctionStatement:
        stmt: FunctionStatement = FunctionStatement()
        # def main() -> int { return 10; }

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.IDENT):
            return None

        stmt.name = IdentifierLiteral(value=self.current_token.literal)

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.LPAREN):
            return None

        stmt.parameters = [] # TODO
        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.RPAREN):
            return None

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.ARROW):
            return None

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.TYPE):
            return None

        stmt.return_type = self.current_token.literal

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.COLON):
            return None

        stmt.body = self.__parse_block_statement()

        return stmt


    def __parse_return_statement(self) -> ReturnStatement:
        stmt: Statement = ReturnStatement()

        self.__next_token()

        stmt.return_value = self.__parse_expression(PrecedenceType.P_LOWEST)

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.SEMICOLON):
            return None

        return stmt

    def __parse_block_statement(self) -> BlockStatement:
        block_stmt: BlockStatement = BlockStatement()

        self.__next_token()

        while not self.__current_token_is(TokenType.EOF):
            if self.current_token.type == TokenType.SEMICOLON:
                self.__next_token()

            stmt: Statement = self.__parse_statement()
            if stmt is not None:
                block_stmt.statements.append(stmt)

            self.__next_token()

        return block_stmt

    def __parse_assign_statement(self) -> AssignStatement:
        stmt: AssignStatement = AssignStatement()

        stmt.ident = IdentifierLiteral(value=self.current_token.literal)

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.EQ):
            return None

        self.__next_token()


        stmt.right_value = self.__parse_expression(PrecedenceType.P_LOWEST)

        if self.__peek_token_is(TokenType.SEMICOLON):
            self.__next_token()

        return stmt

    def __parse_expression(self, precedence: PrecedenceType) -> Expression:
        print(f"Parsing expression, current token: {self.current_token}")

        # Use prefix function only for valid prefix tokens
        prefix_fn = self.prefix_parse_fns.get(self.current_token.type)
        if prefix_fn is None:
            self.__no_prefix_parse_fn_error(self.current_token.type)
            return None

        left_expr = prefix_fn()
        print(f"Left expression: {left_expr}")

        # Ensure we proceed only if the next token has higher precedence
        while not self.__peek_token_is(TokenType.SEMICOLON) and precedence.value < self.__peek_precedence().value:
            infix_fn = self.infix_parse_fns.get(self.peek_token.type)
            if infix_fn is None:
                return left_expr

            # Move to the infix operator and parse accordingly
            self.__next_token()
            left_expr = infix_fn(left_expr)
            print(f"Updated left expression: {left_expr}")

        return left_expr

    def __parse_infix_expression(self, left_node: Expression) -> Expression:
        infix_expr: InfixExpression = InfixExpression(left_node=left_node, operator=self.current_token.literal)

        precedence = self.__current_precedence()

        self.__next_token()

        infix_expr.right_node = self.__parse_expression(precedence)

        return infix_expr

    def __parse_grouped_expression(self) -> Expression:
        self.__next_token()

        expr: Expression = self.__parse_expression(PrecedenceType.P_LOWEST)

        if not self.__expect_peek(TokenType.RPAREN):
            return None

        return expr


    #Region Prefix Methods
    def __parse_identifier(self) -> IdentifierLiteral:
        return IdentifierLiteral(value=self.current_token.literal)


    def __parse_int_literal(self) -> Expression:
        """Parses an IntegerLiteral node from the current token"""
        int_lit: IntegerLiteral = IntegerLiteral()

        try:
            int_lit.value = int(self.current_token.literal)
        except:
            self.errors.append(f"Unable to parse '{self.current_token.literal}' as an integer.")
            return None

        return int_lit

    def __parse_float_literal(self) -> Expression:
        """Parses a FloatLiteral node from the current token"""
        float_lit: FloatLiteral = FloatLiteral()

        try:
            float_lit.value = float(self.current_token.literal)
        except:
            self.errors.append(f"Unable to parse '{self.current_token.literal}' as a float.")
            return None

        return float_lit


main.py:
from Lexer import Lexer
from Parser import Parser
from Compiler import Compiler
from AST import  Program
import json
import time

from llvmlite import ir
import llvmlite.binding as llvm
from ctypes import CFUNCTYPE, c_int, c_float

LEXER_DEBUG: bool = False
PARSER_DEBUG: bool = True
COMPILER_DEBUG: bool = False
RUN_CODE: bool = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("tests/test.py", "r") as f:
        code: str = f.read()

    if LEXER_DEBUG:
        print("===== LEXER DEBUG =====")
        debug_lex: Lexer = Lexer(source=code)
        while debug_lex.current_char is not None:
            print(debug_lex.next_token())

    l: Lexer = Lexer(source=code)
    p: Parser = Parser(l)

    program: Program = p.parse_program()
    if len(p.errors) > 0:
        for err in p.errors:
            print(err)
        exit(1)

    if PARSER_DEBUG:
        print("===== PARSER_DEBUG =====")
        with open("debug/ast.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(program.json(), f, indent=4)

        print("Wrote AST to debug/ast.json successfully")


    c: Compiler = Compiler()
    c.compile(node=program)

    #Output steps
    module: ir.Module = c.module
    module.triple = llvm.get_default_triple()

    if COMPILER_DEBUG:
        with open("debug/ir.ll", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(module))

    if RUN_CODE:
        llvm.initialize()
        llvm.initialize_native_target()
        llvm.initialize_native_asmparser()
        llvm.initialize_native_asmprinter()

        try:
            llvm_ir_parsed = llvm.parse_assembly(str(module))
            llvm_ir_parsed.verify()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise

        target_machine = llvm.Target.from_default_triple().create_target_machine()

        engine = llvm.create_mcjit_compiler(llvm_ir_parsed, target_machine)
        engine.finalize_object()

        entry = engine.get_function_address('main')
        cfunc = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(entry)

        # Compile time
        st = time.time() #start time
        result = cfunc()
        et = time.time() # end time

        print(f'\n\nProgram returned: {result}\n==== Executed in {round((et - st) * 1000, 3)}ms ====')



test.py (file i am testing)
def main() -> int:
    a: int = 4;

    a = a * 2;

    return a;

I have tried various ways but can't seem to find figure it out.
It looks like the current token is starting from the second line in test.py and not from the 4th line (a = a + 2) where it should be starting from.

there is too much code, please read [mre]
